# Dispatching to overloaded standardGeneric methods in R

Tags: r, plot, overloading, r-s4

Consider the following complete R example:

```
setClass("foo", representation(data = "data.frame"))

if (!isGeneric("plot"))
  setGeneric("plot", function(x, y, ...) standardGeneric("plot"))

setMethod(f = "plot", 
          signature(x = "foo", y = 'missing'),
          definition = function(x, y, ...) {
            plot(data$x, data$y)
          }
)

fooObject = new('foo', data=data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y =rnorm(100)))
```

Plotting the object fails as follows:

```
> plot(fooObject)
Error in as.double(y) : 
  cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

The cause, seemingly, is that the generic plot() function is being called for the S4 object fooObject.  However, the correct (?) method seems to exist.  Clearly, my definition of 'correct' is off.  Can someone explain what's going on?

```
> showMethods('plot')
Function: plot (package graphics)
x="ANY", y="ANY"
x="bootFlexclust", y="missing"
x="color", y="ANY"
x="foo", y="missing"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simply that you are not accessing the slots of your object. Try this :

```
setMethod(f = "plot", 
    signature(x = "foo", y = "missing"),
    definition = function(x, y, ...) {
        slotdata<-x@data
        plot(slotdata$x, slotdata$y)
    }
)
```

I had a similar problem of a function plot defined inside a package which continued to use the graphics standard Generics :

```
Error in as.double(x) : 
cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'
```

It turns out that I had forgotten to export it when building the package.